# How to draw a line with css and show text or image on it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to draw a line using CSS and show text/image in the middle of the line.

```css
.featured-images {
  color: #666666;
  border: 2px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<p class="featured-images">Featured</p>
```

This is what I want to do:

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the text inside a `span` and use a :pseudo-element for the line.

Position the line(:pseudo-element) behind the `span` using `z-index: -1`, so that you could move around the text without having to worry about the line.

```css
.featured-images {
  position: relative;
  color: #666666;
  border: 2px solid #333333;
  padding: 0 10px 0 30px;
}
.featured-images span {
  color: #666666;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.featured-images:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #666666;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p class="featured-images"><span>Featured</span></p>
```

---

Replicating the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You could use `repeating-linear-gradient` to do this.

```css
body {
  background: #E7EAE3;
}
.featured-images {
  position: relative;
  color: #666666;
  padding: 0 10px 0 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.featured-images span {
  color: #517575;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.featured-images:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #463A3A 10px, #F2F2F2 10px, #F2F2F2 11px, #463A3A 11px, #463A3A 20px) repeat-x;
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #463A3A 10px, #F2F2F2 10px, #F2F2F2 11px, #463A3A 11px, #463A3A 20px) repeat-x;
  background-size: 10px 31px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p class="featured-images"><span>Featured</span>
</p>
```

---

Using image instead of text.

```css
.featured-images {
  position: relative;
  color: #666666;
  border: 2px solid #333333;
  padding: 0 10px 0 30px;
}
.featured-images span {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 13px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/80/13) no-repeat white 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.featured-images:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #666666;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p class="featured-images"><span></span></p>
```

Comment: yes very cool thank you! additionally i see any time something like this. I really wonder how you do that.http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-781njLjo92I/VLK_uDingSI/AAAAAAAAAEU/Wfp6fBuuzp0/s1600/11-01-2015%2B20-21-37.jpg i mean, sometimes i see that with with layed right down slash

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32bqL26t/1/)

CSS:

```
.featured-images {
    color: #666666;
}
p span {
    margin:0;padding: 0 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
}
p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;   
}
p:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px #666666;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: yes very cool thank you! additionally i see any time something like this. I really wonder how you do that.http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-781njLjo92I/VLK_uDingSI/AAAAAAAAAEU/Wfp6fBuuzp0/s1600/11-01-2015%2B20-21-37.jpg

Answer (score 2):

**Demo 1**

[image]

```css
:root{padding: 40px}
p{

    position: relative;
    margin:40px auto;padding:0 10px;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
}
p:before,p:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    right:0
}
p:before{
    top:-4px;
    left: -24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 480px;
    border:solid 1px #666666
}
p:after{
    top: 50%;
    width: 466px;
    left: -16px;
    border-top: solid 1px #666666
}
```

```html
<p class="featured-images">Featured</p>
```

Use Pseudo element

```css
:root{padding: 40px}
p{

    position: relative;
    margin:40px auto;padding:0 10px;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
}
p:before,p:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    left:-14px;
    right:0;
    width: 480px
}
p:before{
    top:-4px;
    height: 24px;
    border:solid 1px #666666
}
p:after{
    top:50%;
    border-top:solid 1px #666666
}
```

```html
<p class="featured-images">Featured</p>
```

Demo 2

```css
p{

    position: relative;
    margin:0;padding:0 10px;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
}

p:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:-14px;
    right:0;
    width: 100vw;
    border-top:solid 1px #666666;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<p class="featured-images">Featured</p>
```

**Update**

[image]

```css
:root{padding: 40px}
p{

    position: relative;
    margin:40px auto;padding:0 10px;
    background:white;
    display:inline-block;
}
p:before,p:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    right:0
}
p:before{
    top:-4px;
    left: -24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 480px;
    border:solid 1px #666666;
    background-color: gray;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 2px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 2px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 6px)
}
}
p:after{
    top: 50%;
    width: 466px;
    left: -16px;
    border-top: solid 1px #666666
}
```

```html
<p class="featured-images">Featured</p>
```

Comment: yes very cool thank you! additionally i see any time something like this. I really wonder how you do that.http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-781njLjo92I/VLK_uDingSI/AAAAAAAAAEU/Wfp6fBuuzp0/s1600/11-01-2015%2B20-21-37.jpg i mean, sometimes i see that with with layed right down slash

Answer (score 0):

Result http://jsfiddle.net/p8jdzqvL/embedded/result/

```
 <div style="height: 2px; background-color: black; text-align: center">
      <span style="background-color: white; position: relative; top: -0.5em;">
        Stay Connected
      </span>
    </div>
```